# Embedding bash commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm using `virtualenvwrapper` and trying to create a virtualenv using a version of python that's not the default.

What I'd like to do is:

```
$ which python2.7
>> /usr/local/bin/python2.7
$ mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python2.7 env
```

...But without the copy-paste. Is there a way to do this in one line?

Comment: Are you asking how to write a BASH script to do that?

Comment: `mkvirtualenv -p "$(type -P python2.7)" env`

Comment: Well, a one-line bash script

Comment: I don't have `type`, @kojiro , but `mkvirtualenv -p "$(which python2.7)" env` works. I'll accept it if you write it as an answer --thanks!

Comment: @miguel5 You should have `type`. It's a [POSIX standard utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/type.html). `which` is nonstandard. What system are you using that doesn't have `type`?

Comment: @miguel5 ah, however, if you try to use `which` to find `type`, you may fail because `type` is a built-in.

Comment: That's why I was unable to find it... thanks, @kojiro !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mkvirtualenv -p "$(type -P python2.7)" env
```

is the correct way to write this as a one-liner. `type` is a [POSIX standard utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/type.html), so it is more likely to exist and work consistently across POSIX-ish systems than `which`.